# Choosing a design pattern for a class that might change its internal attributes

Tags: c++, design-patterns, oop

I have a class that holds arbitrary state and it's defined like this:

```
class AbstractFoo
{
};

template <class StatePolicy>
class Foo : public StatePolicy, public AbstractFoo
{
};
```

The state policy contains only protected attributes that represent the state.
The state **might** be the same for multiple behaviors and they can be replaced at runtime.
All Foo objects have the same interface to abstract the state itself and to enable storing Foo objects in containers.
I would like to find the least verbose and the most maintainable way to express this.

EDIT:
Here's some more info on my problem:
Foo is a class that represents a state and behavior of a certain hardware that can be changed either physically or through a UI (and there are multiple UIs).
I have four more questions:
1) Would a signal/slot mechanism will do?
2) Is it possible to bind every emitted signal from a slot in Foo to have a pointer to Foo like it's a member class?
3) Should I use a visitor instead and treat Foo as a visited class?
4) Why is the StatePolicy a bad design?

Here's the updated API:

```
class AbstractFoo
{
public:
  virtual void /*or boost::signal*/ notify() = 0; // Updates the UI.
  virtual void /*or boost::signal*/ updateState() = 0 // Updates the state
};
```

Comment: Would virtual functions, polymorphism, or storing pointers to objects help?  Sorry, I'm just trying to understand your question.

Comment: Of course virtual functions exist as the interface is the same. But the behavior of the API for each object MIGHT change on runtime.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand your situation exactly, but here's my shot at it:  what if you make an `AbstractStatePolicy` instead?  Example:

```
class AbstractStatePolicy
{
};

class Foo
{
    AbstractStatePolicy *state_policy;

public:
    Foo(AbstractStatePolicy *state_policy)
        : state_policy(state_policy)
    {
    }
};
```

This way, instead of statically defining `Foo` as a template using a `StatePolicy`, you can dynamically set the `StatePolicy` using an approach like this.

If you don't like the idea of having to specify the state_policy every time you create a `Foo`, consider using a default value or writing a factory to instantiate `Foo`s.

Comment: +1 that's as simple as it gets. Plus, you get to avoid that arbitrary multiple inheritance thing there!

Comment: I've been told if you have to use multiple inheritance, re-think your design ;)  +1

Comment: @Robb: Multiple inheritance is right for some cases, if you hate it go program Java.

Comment: @Robb: it's not always the case, but that's a good guideline nonetheless, most of the times you don't need multi-inheritance :)

Comment: It was just a piece of advice I was told by a programmer I highly respected.  We don't need to start an argument about it, at least not here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you have is a very sensible approach. You should have a pure virtual base class that describes what your implementations  can actually do, and then you can create concrete classes that inherit from the base class using whatever state you would need. You would then be able to interact with the state through whatever interface you defined for that base class. Now, if you have arbitrary, dynamic attributes that can change at runtime, then a good way to accomplish that is with a map or dictionary type; you can either map from strings (names of attributes) to strings (representing the attribute values), or if you want a little bit more type safety, you map from strings (names of attributes), to instances of [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: But that is very verbose. I don't want to create a class for each behavior.